# Recoding (real-time) large-size images on a usb stick with [ROS bag]

Tags: image, compression, usb, size, ros

The quality of the record images is a key importance. Thus am not sure if `rosbag record /camera/image_raw/compressed` is relevant to this case, since it is reported that the compressed mode is lossy...

There should a manner that even when the rostopic stops, the copying on the usb continues. Like this, one will not have frame drops.

Any advice/solution?

Note that the image streaming needs to be at a decent frequency.

Answer (score 4):

From your question I assume that your images are too large / arrive too frequently to be able to be written in real-time on your USB stick.

Depending on your setup/requirements, consider writing the bag to hard disk and copy it over to USB later.

If you need to write directly to your USB stick, obviously the only solution is to reduce the amount of data to be written. Do not rule out `/camera/image_raw/compressed` for that. By default it compresses data as JPEG (lossy), but you can switch it to PNG (lossless). Simply start your software and run `rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure`. For the image transport you should see an entry where you can switch from JPEG to PNG ([source code](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins/blob/indigo-devel/compressed_image_transport/cfg/CompressedPublisher.cfg)). You should be able to set this value (namespace.format = "png") in your launch file, too ([ref](http://answers.ros.org/question/28327/dynamic-reconfigure-default-parameters/)).

You could also reduce the image resolution or framerate, if that is acceptable. In combination with PNG compression, this would be your best bet.

If you don't want to compress as lossless PNG, another (less efficient) option is to have rosbag store compressed data (`--lz4` will not consume much CPU, but will not yield the best compression results; `--bz2` will save more space but may impact your real-time requirements depending on your CPU and load)

Comment: Thanks @dseifert. Could you pls share how to force PNG format when recording compressed images as a bag file?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically you can set a parameter in the launch file, which will get picked up by dynamic_reconfigure.